# Xcode automatically goes to lldb when trying to divide two float numbers

Tags: c, division, lldb

I've got a program written in C, running in Xcode 4.6, where one of the functions divides two float numbers based on user input. For some reason, the program pauses and turns on the `lldb` debugger in a seemingly endless loop when I try to do the division in the right order (code sample 1), and, when I try to invert the division, the result is always zero (code sample 2).

sample 1 code:

```
float num2, num1;
int main() {
    scanf("%f",&num1);
    scanf("%f",&num2);

    num2 = num1/num2;

    printf("%f",num2);
}
```

sample 1 output:

```
4
2      // user inputs calculation

(lldb)   // program keeps printing this indefinitely
```

sample 2 code:

```
float num2, num2
int main() {
    scanf("%f",&num1);
    scanf("%f",&num2);

    num2 = num2/num1;

    printf("%f",num2);
}
```

sample 2 output:

```
4
2        // user inputs calculation

0        // since calculation is inverted, input was interpreted as 2/4, but rather than returning 0.5, the program returns 0.
```

Not sure why this happens, or how to fix it. Anyone here had a similar issue and found a fix?

Comment: Well, what does LLDB show? What are `num1` and num2?

Comment: Also, your sample 2 code doesn't print anything. How can you say its output is zero?

Comment: `lldb` shows that `num1` is the first number the user inputted (the correct number), but that `num2` is 0.

Comment: I may have been too selective in dropping the irrelevant code. I'll add the `printf()` lines.

Comment: Your quasi-declaration, `float num2, num2` lacks a semicolon, and "declares" `num2` twice, but not `num1`.

Comment: The rule, usually, is that you should narrow down the simplest code _in which your problem still happens_. If you can run this without issues, then your problem is most likely not there, and it's not very useful to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not again, please... This is C, not C++. You need to pass pointers to the variables as the arguments of `scanf()` in order it to be able to modify (i. e. write to) them:

```
scanf("%f", &num1);
            ^
          This!
```

Comment: @user2129150 Copy-paste code, don't guess. I hate my answers being proved wrong because of a typo (which is not my fault and *is* out of scope).

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. The computer with the code can't get online, so I'm asking off another machine.

Comment: Also, as-is, the code doesn't compile. If I fix it, it works.

Comment: Actually, I tried putting just the excerpt I posted into a new Xcode project, it compiles and works perfectly. Still can't get it to work _as part_ of another program.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see the output from `printf` in example 1 is because you're missing the `\n` at the end of the string to add a new line.  lldb won't print that output to you until the line has been finished.